# Creating a "hanging" pipe in cascading

Tags: cascading

Basically in my FlowDef, I want to do a join on my tuples with some other tuples that I will be reading via an API. So I created another empty pipe and I'm filling it with tuples from the API using a Function. Then I do a CoGroup and use that as the tail Pipe.

```
Tap tap1 = new Hfs();
Pipe pipe1 = new Pipe("pipe1");

Pipe pipeFromApi = new Pipe("pipeFromApi");
Pipe joinPipe = new CoGroup(pipe1, pipeFromApi);
Tap tap2 = new Hfs();

flowDef.addSource(pipe1, tap1).addTailSink(joinPipe, tap2);
```

This causes the following error - "pipe name not found in either sink or source map: 'pipeFromApi'".

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dummy SinkTap and make it the "source" of pipeFromApi.

The exception says pipe "pipeFromApi" does not have a tap - while every pipe should have one.

Answer (score 0):

A Pipe in Cascading is used to name branches of pipe assemblies, which is used during planning to bind Taps as either sources or sinks. A Tap is data source or data sink of a Pipe assembly. It is very clear from these definitions that inorder to carry the data which is sourced by a Tap, you need to bind it with the Pipe. In your code you have defined the Pipe pipeFromApi but have not created any source(Tap) for this. Also, after you create this Tap, you need to bind your Pipe pipeFromApi with this newly created Tap in flowDef. Then only the flow will be able to recognise two input source one being your pipe1 and another being your pipeFromApi.
So the correct code snippet might look like this :

```
Tap tap1 = new Hfs("..inputSource");
Pipe pipe1 = new Pipe("pipe1");

Tap tap2 = new Hfs("..inputSourceFromApi");
Pipe pipeFromApi = new Pipe("pipeFromApi");

Tap tap3 = new Hfs("..outputSinkDestination");
Pipe joinPipe = new CoGroup(pipe1, pipeFromApi);

flowDef.addSource(pipe1, tap1).addSource(pipeFromApi, tap2).addTailSink(joinPipe, tap3);
```